# Pixel 6 Pro - system taking up over 200gb of memory

Tags: storage, google-pixel-6, android-14

- Pixel 6 Pro
- Android 14
- 256Gb storage

About a week ago my phone began complaining about a lack of storage - there was only about 2Gb left!  I've done a bit of a tidy up and freed another 4Gb but yesterday I realised the System is taking up 224Gb!!

I've spent the last 24 hours googling and searching on YT and on here but without rooting it I can't see any way to clean up this storage (which appears to be at least 100Gb more than it should be) or even see what's happening.

I'd rather not do a factory reset but that's what I'm facing if I can't find a solution here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's the `/system` partition gobbling up huge space, I doubt if there is anything that can be done by the user (even on a rooted device, since the partition is "read only"), except:

1. [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset)

**Caveat**: I haven't tried the options below on my Pixel 4a/6a

2. Flashing the stock ROM again *without* the `-w` before running the `flash-all` script
   to prevent data wipe.
3. Flashing factory image flashing in fastboot with force option on (see [this guide for both options 2 and 3](https://www.androidpolice.com/how-to-use-adb-or-flash-tool-to-manually-install-google-pixel-updates/)).

IMO it's best to jump to option 3 with *force* option enabled (without wiping data), since this involves [dynamic partition](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/dynamic_partitions#:%7E:text=Dynamic%20partitions%20are%20a%20userspace,system%20%2C%20vendor%20%2C%20and%20product%20.) sizing glitch. The force option apparently fixes dynamic partition sizing based on what the *developer*  of [PixelFlasher, a GUI tool for flashing / updating / rooting / managing Pixel phones](https://xdaforums.com/t/pixelflasher-a-gui-tool-for-flashing-updating-rooting-managing-pixel-phones.4415453/page-108) says [here](https://xdaforums.com/t/pixelflasher-a-gui-tool-for-flashing-updating-rooting-managing-pixel-phones.4415453/post-89190896):

> Full OTA is indeed full ROM, but based on observation, when it comes to switching firmware, or even downgrading, it does not work, I suspect that *it does not do partition resizing.*
> I do quite a bit of messing up on my test phone and often *I had to resort to factory image flashing in fastboot with force option on.*

(Emphasis supplied)

I wanted to put all this in comments since I haven't tried these options but it was getting to be too long, so made an answer of it, more as a pointer towards possibilities then a definitive course of action.

Comment: I did a factory reset - system is now less than 20gb(!) and the backup restored most of my apps so a result in the end!

Comment: Good that's fixed. Just in case it was due to malware, and happens again (hope not), you may have to try option 3 ( see [first para of answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236334/security-on-a-nexus-6p-purchased-on-ebay/236338#236338)

Comment: Sadly it has happened again so am now trying option 3.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, all the best. It may/not be malware, it could be partition sizes glitch as quoted in the answer